# Fiddler doesn't show HTTPS traffic from git bash client

Tags: bash, git, fiddler, git-bash

Just for fun, I set up Fiddler to trace HTTPS traffic and I have my git bash client configured to use HTTPS rather than SSH.

I went to **Tools -> Telerik Fiddler Options -> HTTPS** and ticked both the check-boxes **Capture HTTPS Connects** and **Decrypt HTTPS traffic** and left the selection **from all processes...** selected in the drop-down. Still, Fiddler does not show me the HTTPs traffic sent or received by my git bash client.

Why? And can I make it show me that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things:

1. I had forgotten to set up Fiddler's root certificate and register it on my machine and user profile's certificate store. With that set up, Fiddler does intercept HTTPS traffic to any host, and so even to GitHub.
2. Upon observing an intercepted request on my own machine for one of my own repositories, I observed that the git bash client does send an HTTPS request to the GitHub API at the endpoint `https://api.github.com/user/subscriptions` to retrieve a user's subscriptions, i.e. a list of repositories the user is entitled to commit to, as a part of a pre-push validation.

   But then it does not send the actual bits composing the commit over HTTPS. I take it that it sends them on a raw TCP connection.

I think this is where this answer should be left at.